# How to skim (plaster) a tight corner under stairs?

Tags: drywall, plaster

I need to skim an area of wall below some stairs. There's a tight corner where the boards below the upstairs stairs meet a length of trim:

[image]

Annoyingly, this is pretty much at eye level for anyone going down the lower set of stairs so I want to get a reasonable looking finish. (I'm using board finish on plasterboard.)

Any tips for getting into tight corners like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mason's trowel. Or you can cut and modify a low cost 6 inch putty knife to fit the angle. When using either, drag the point out from the corner and keep the point of the tool in contact with either adjacent surface.